# WooCommerce проблема с версткой одного момента

Tags: html, css, wordpress, вёрстка, woocommerce

Как видно на скриншоте, кнопка уехала в право, а чекбокс и текстом вообще съехали. Я не совсем понимаю, как это можно исправить.

Сайт www.osmo.pro.
Заходите на него, берёте хотя-бы один товар в корзину, переходите на страницу оплаты, нажимаете "Уже покупали? Нажмите для авторизации".

Пожалуйста, помогите если кто реально может. Даже совет, может помочь.
Если что-то не понятно, уточняйте в комментариях.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно какой результат вы ожидаете. Как должен выглядеть чекбокс, подпись и кнопка?

Comment: Сложно сказать, но точно не так. Видно же, что слетело что-то. Например как на скриншоте ниже. Это я установил просто на другую тему то-же самое. https://imgur.com/a/nff8k6q

Answer (score 0):

Удалите width отсюда:

```
.woocommerce-checkout input {
    width: 100%
}
```

И добавьте так с указанием типа input'a:

```
.woocommerce-checkout input[type=text],
... // Может быть еще какие-то типы надо)
.woocommerce-checkout input[type=tel],
.woocommerce-checkout input[type=email],
.woocommerce-checkout input[type=number] {
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: Сделал, получилось не совсем верно. https://imgur.com/P0OGpMW